# <> convert to &lt; &gt; in RubyXL::Parser in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, xlsx

I am using `RubyXL::Parser` to parse `xlsx` file which is uploaded by users. When sending text `<> &` but after parsing it converted in `&lt; &gt; &amp;`. Why this is happening. I want origin characters entered by user.
What can I do here?

Comment: `XML` does this. You can get rid of it, by using `#gsub`.. to replace those.

Comment: But why. User may enter &lt, in text, so we can't `gsub` it

Comment: I saw in my recent work, that XML does it, and get rid over it as I said.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents

Comment: And this [one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)

Comment: @Arup: can you please let me know how can I escape these characters. If possible can you give an example from your works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mine was not user inputs. I had a template(word doc), where erb codes were written. Now, as the doc was OpenOffice Word doc, it always save then as XML, and XML converts all `<` , `>` etc are as per its equivalent. So, before parsing the XML, I just reset those using `#gsub`. This is what I did in my case.